# Wordpress: Customizing the 'Add new post' in Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, menu, widget, admin

Is there any way I could customize the 'Add new post' page in the Wordpress Admin Panel? I'm trying to add some extra menus, among the default 'Publish', 'Categories', 'Tags' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `add_meta_box()` in your `functions.php`

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box